# Eclipse skipping breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

My issue isn't a new one, and I found several threads about it, yet no one was helpful for me.
I hope this one will.

I can't debug with eclipse. It recognizes breakpoints, switches to debug view, but somehow it gets out of sync and I can't debug my code. Sometimes It works, but after a while It happens again.

I work with JDK 1.6.0_24, Glassfish 3.1, eclipse INDIGO (but it also happens on HELIOS).

I tried (as I found in this site) to set eclipse to use Parallel GC. I tried put it in the eclipse.ini file, I tried to put in the glassfish VM arguments itself, and I tried to put it at eclipse JDK additional VM arguments (preference -> installed JRE-> JDK -> etc). Nothing seem to work for me. I also tried them all together.

Help me please..

Thank you all from advance,
Ido

**EDIT:**

OK, I noticed few more things:

On the Debug view, in my stck trace, I found the exact class with the breakpoint is paused and it had this comment: "(Suspended breakpoint at line XX)". When I clicked the line, suddenly the green line appeared. Yet, as soon as I clicked F6 to continue, It went out of sync again, just the next line became suspended. Weird.

I checked the processes running on my computer and found that there are several "java.exe" processes running at the same time. (eclipse runs on javaw.exe). Maybe this is why glassfish and eclipse refuse to work together.

I checked the build path and found that this is my output folder: project-name/target/classes. Is this good?

Any thoughts?

Ido

Comment: are you sure that your classes are compiled with your latest sources? That may cause some debug troubles if they are not.

Comment: just execute clean/build in Eclipse. Sometimes this autosync can be uncomplete due to some magical resons :)

Comment: Its surprising even for eclipse developer too. are you sure you are putting the break point at right point ? Or is this something debug is not working at all in your eclipse?

Comment: clean and build does not change anything.

Comment: And Im sure about the breakpoints.

Comment: No error at all. Eclipse moves to debug prespective, opens the right class with the breakpoint but there is no green line, and i cant use F5,F6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I couldn't fix this but I found a workaround that completely solves this - FINALLY!.

I just stopped using glassfish WTP for debugging and set a remote debug to my local glassfish. it works perfectly with few minor annoying things - but breakpoints finally noticed.

**Set remote debug**

1. Go to your glassfish admin console and set your glassfish to work on debug mode. 
   Click on configuration --> server-config --> JVM settings, and check debug enabled check box. 
   Restart server
2. In eclipse - start server on normal mode (not debug - it is useless).
3. Go to Debug configurations and locate "Remote Java Application"
4. Create a new Remote java app debug config
5. Enter name (lets say Glassfish-Debug)
6. Choose project to debug
7. Enter **your own IP address** in the host section and set the port to **9009** 
   [image]
8. This is optional but it is more comfortable to work with: 
    Go to "Common" tab, and check the Debug check box. 
    This will make this Glassfish remote debugging configuration constant on your debug menu.
   [image]

That's it. Now all you have to do is always start your Glassfish in normal mode and then go to Debug configurations and run This Glassfish remote debugging you just set. 
[image]

And now I'm getting to the annoying part: After rebuild your project, sometimes you might get again out of sync. You just need to disconnect the remote debugging session and run it again. Small price to pay.

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issues, But it turned out to be a simpler problem of multiple versions of JREs/JDKs installed.

Try Debug -> Run Configuration -> JRE -> Alternate JRE -> select JDK 1.6.0_24.

Also check for project build paths if correct Jars are been used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have only one JRE installed - This one.